# Trying to show if $a=(b+1)c+\frac{1}{2}b(b-1)$ then $a\not=2^d+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

If $a=(b+1)c+\frac{1}{2}b(b-1)$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$, how might I show that $a\not=2^d+1$ where $d\in\mathbb{Z}, d\ge 0$? I have tested this with brute force and it seems to hold - with the only numbers not of this form being a some power of 2 plus one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are such $a,b,c,d$ that:

$$ 2(b+1)c+b(b-1)= 2^{d+1}+2$$
then we have $$(b+1)(2c+b-2)= 2^{d+1}$$
so $b+1$ is even (else $b+1=1$ and so $b=0$ which is impossible) and thus $b$ is odd, but then $2c+b-2$ is odd which is impossible unless $2c+b-2=1$. But then $b=c=1$ so $a=2$.